# How to Add/Delete topic and subscription in Azure Servicebus automatically using command line

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, command-line, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to write simple console application which can automatically **Add or Delete any Azure Service Bus Topics and subscription from 
Service Bus explorer 3.0.4** but no luck so far.

Code is in C# / Visual Studio 2015 about service and messaging and pubsub is creating Azure token Key automatically.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Add or Delete any Azure Service Bus Topics and subscription from Service Bus explorer 3.0.4

If understood correctly, you mean delete from Azure Service Bus. [SB Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/) is just a tool to manage ASB entities.

You can use the current client [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) or [Service Bus management libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus) that is still in preview. The latter will require AAD and is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-management-libraries). The client would require a token.